# Updating cask Generic Artifact Source not found

Tags: java, homebrew

I'm trying to update my homebrew java installation, i'm getting this error unfortunately

```
 brew upgrade
==> Casks with `auto_updates` or `version :latest` will not be upgraded
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
java 13.0.2,8:d4173c853231432d94f001e99d882ca7 -> 14.0.2,12:205943a0976c4ed48cb16f1043c5c647
==> Upgrading java
==> Downloading https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14.0.2/205943a0976c4ed48cb16f1043c5c647/12/GPL/openjdk-14.0.2_osx-x64_bin.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/omar/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/4a16d10e8fdff3dd085a21e2ddd1d0ff91dba234c8c5f6588bff9752c845bebb--openjdk-14.0.2_osx-x64_bin.tar.gz
==> Verifying SHA-256 checksum for Cask 'java'.
==> Purging files for version 14.0.2,12:205943a0976c4ed48cb16f1043c5c647 of Cask java
Error: It seems the Generic Artifact source '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-13.0.2.jdk' is not there.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix is to reinstall with the --no-quarantine flag, in my case as so

`brew cask reinstall --no-quarantine java`

### Update Sep 2023

Now cask isn't a command so the updated version is : `brew reinstall --cask --no-quarantine java` -[@Aurélien Foucault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10419533/aur%C3%A9lien-foucault)

Comment: should that have been `brew cask reinstall --no-quarantine adoptopenjdk` ?

Comment: My problem was with Java, if yours is with adoptopenjdk then yes.

Comment: My bad. Carry on sir.

Comment: Now cask isn't a command so the updated version is :  `brew reinstall --cask --no-quarantine java`